# Как с помощью команды Invoke-WebRequest получить StatusCode 301?

Tags: http, get, powershell

Читаю книгу "RESTful Web APIs" 2013 года.
На странице 35 там написано, что обычный ответ на запрос GET это код 200.
И действительно, если дать команду `curl ya.ru` то я получаю 200 в ответ.
Также там написано, что код 301 тоже распространён.

Я в течение часа пытаюсь найти адрес, который мне в ответ даст 301 и не могу найти.
Возможно, что powershell просто сам перенаправляет мой запрос.

Итак, вопрос. Приведите пример, какой командой в `powershell` или любым другим инструментом я могу получить в ответ на мой запрос GET - код 301.

Приведите команду и адрес такого ресурса, который мне в ответ даст код перенаправления 301.
И чтобы при этом не происходило фактического перенаправления и я бы в консоли увидел код 301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

301 не так уж сильно распространен. Это "moved permanently".
Выдаётся на GET или HEAD.

В cmd я получил сейчас `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` дав команду

`curl -I http://blog.ahrefs.com`

Поэксперементируйте с этим адресом.

Сайт [www.example.org](http://www.example.org) командой типа: `GET /index.php HTTP/1.1`
тоже раньше давал 301, как понимаю, но через curl я получил 200.

Не уверен, кстати, что `powershell` не обработает редирект сам. Тогда можете не увидеть 301.

Comment: Да, спасибо. На убунту я написал ```curl blog.ahrefs.com``` в терминале и получил в ответ ```<html><head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head><body><center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center><hr><center>nginx</center></body></html>```

Comment: ещё нашёл адрес ```curl -i ya.org```